# Sort an ArrayList by an object's attribute in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparable

I wish to sort my objects in order of their Email address.

This is the method I've attempted but it does not work, but I'm not even sure it's the correct way to do what I want?

```
public static ArrayList<Billing> sortedListByEmail(ArrayList<Billing> Billing) {
    ArrayList<Billing> Sort = new ArrayList<Billing>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Sort.size(); i++) {
        Collections.sort(Sort, new Comparator<Billing>() {
            public int compare(Billing o1, Billing o2) {
                return o1.getEmail() > o2.getEmail() ? -1 : o1.getEmail().equals(o2.getEmail() ? 0 : 1);
            }
        });
    }

    return Sort;
}
```

Rest of the class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Billing extends User implements Comparable<User> {
    private Address billingAddress;
    private String email;

    public Billing(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, UserType userType, PermissionType permission, Boolean Status, Address billingAddress, String email) {
        super(id, firstName, lastName, userName, password, userType, permission, Status);

        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Billing(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, UserType userType, PermissionType permission, Boolean Status, String email) {
        super(id, firstName, lastName, userName, password, userType, permission, Status);

    }

    public Billing(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, UserType userType, PermissionType permission, Boolean Status) {
        super(id, firstName, lastName, userName, password, userType, permission, Status);
    }

    public Address getBillingAddress() {
        return billingAddress;
    }

    public void setBillingAddress(Address billingAddress) {
        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish sorting the objects in order of their email address? Thank you

Comment: You are sorting empty list on each iteration...

Comment: You shouldn't be sorting the list in a loop. Also, since the email is a String, why not just use String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER as the comparator?

Comment: Btw. why are you calling `.sort()` on an empty list and inside of a loop?

Comment: @Amongalen im really just mucking around the code to see what works so alot of what ive posted probably doesnt make sense but i just wanted to demonstrate what ive attempted :)

Comment: @BalzGuenat our lab professor gave us a hint that we're meant to iterate through the list and then use a sorting API like collections.sort or comparators

Answer (score 6):

try the below code :

```
billingList.sort(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getEmail));
```

Comment: I believe that should be `a -> a.getEmail()`.

Comment: Maybe you've meant `Collections.sort()` instead? `Billing` doesn't have `sort()` as far as I know.

Comment: Since Java 8 it has. Check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). Because `List` has this method.

Comment: Amongalen meant `billingList.sort` or such. A typo on your side. `billings.sort(Comparator.compairing(Billing::getEmail));`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I have updated the answer.

Comment: I believe you could also try: `Comparator.comparing(Billing::getEmail)`

Answer (score 2):

Since the `email` is a `String` and also a `Comparable` you can use the `String.compareTo` to sort using the `email` property. (This is a pre Java-8 solution):

```
public static List<Billing> sortedListByEmail(List<Billing> Billing) {
    List<Billing> sort = new ArrayList<>(Billing);
    Collections.sort(sort, new Comparator<Billing>() {
            public int compare(Billing o1, Billing o2) {
                   return o1.getEmail().compareTo(o2.getEmail());
            }
      }
   );
   return sort;
}
```

In Java-8 this can be made more compact, with the `Comparator#comparing`:

```
public static List<Billing> sortedListByEmail(List<Billing> Billing) {
        List<Billing> sorted = new ArrayList<>(Billing);
        sorted.sort(Comparator.comparing(b -> b.getEmail()));
        return sorted;
}
```

Here the original list supplied is not sorted in place, instead a copy is made which is sorted.

Or you can use `Stream#sorted` to do it in an elegant way which will also return you a new `List` instead of modifying the original one:

```
public static List<Billing> sortedListByEmail(List<Billing> Billing) {
    return Billing.stream()
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(b -> b.getEmail()))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it old ways then got for below code

```
    public static ArrayList<Billing> sortedListByEmail(ArrayList<Billing> Billing) {

    Collections.sort(Billing, new Comparator<Billing>() {
        public int compare(Billing o1, Billing o2) {
            return o1.getEmail().compareTo(o2.getEmail());
        }
    });

    return Billing;
}
```

Few things you are doing wrong in your code -
First - `return o1.getEmail() > o2.getEmail() ? -1 : o1.getEmail().equals(o2.getEmail() ? 0 : 1);` you cannot compare a string value like integer value.

Second - You are creating an empty array list and sorting it. It has no elements, it is empty.
`ArrayList<Billing> Sort = new ArrayList<Billing>(); ........
Collections.sort(Sort, new Comparator<Billing>() {`

With java 8 features it can be done in very less line of code as below

```
billing.sort(Comparator.comparing(b -> b.getEmail()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change the existing array, no need of new variable,

```
Collections.sort(billingList, Comparator.comparing(Billing::getEmail));
```

Answer (score 0):

With considering that Billing List object name is `billingList`

**1) If you are using Java 8 you can do it using below approaches:**

*Using Collections.sort with Lambda expression:*

```
Collections.sort(billingList, (b1, b2) -> b1.getEmail().compareTo(b2.getEmail()));
```

*Using sort method of List Interface (default method)*

```
billingList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Billing::getEmail));
```

**2) If you are using earlier version of Java**

```
Collections.sort(billingList, new Comparator<Billing>() {

      public int compare(final Billing b1, final Billing b2) {

        return b1.getEmail().compareTo(b2.getEmail());

      };
    });
```