# Sorting an array list of custom java classes based on variable

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a custom Java class which contains two variables: `username` and `score`.

I am looking to create an ArrayList with multiple of these inside. I then want to sort them in order of lowest to highest, based on the value of their `score`

Highscore.class

```
public class Highscore implements ConfigurationSerializable {

    String username;
    int score;

    public Highscore(String username, int score) {
        this.username = username;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> serialize() {
        Map<String, Object> mappedObject = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        mappedObject.put("username", username);
        mappedObject.put("score", score);
        return mappedObject;
    }

    public static Highscore deserialize(Map<String, Object> mappedObject) {
        return new Highscore((String) mappedObject.get("username"),
                (int) mappedObject.get("score"));
    }
}
```

For example, below shows the ArrayList containing multiple `Highscore`'s. I want to look only at the `score` based on low to high, and then sort the `Highscore`'s into another ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Highscore> highscores = new ArrayList<>();
highscores.add(new Highscore("user1", 10));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user2", 0));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user3", -15));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user4", 30));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user5", 5));

// Now, sort the highscores based on their 'score'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an ArrayList by an object's attribute in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870812/sort-an-arraylist-by-an-objects-attribute-in-java)

Comment: It has multiple solutions to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/57871457/4762502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you really restricted to use only `List`?

IMO [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) is better suited for your goal. You can use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
Notice that `TreeSet` elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time. Also, it provides guaranteed `log(n)` time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains), so it's computationally pretty efficient.

For example, you can do the following:

```
SortedSet<Highscore> highscores =
  new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(highscore -> highscore.score));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user1", 10));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user2", 0));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user3", -15));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user4", 30));
highscores.add(new Highscore("user5", 5));
```

Now `highscores` contains all your objects sorted ascending by `score`.

Also, if you need to get `List` from `highscores`, then simply:

```
List<Highscore> highscoreList = new ArrayList<>(highscores);
```

The advantage of this approach: is better flexibility and efficiency, because after `SortedSet` is formed any queries will cost you `O(log n)` or `O(n)` time. And if you use `List` you will always be forced to perform sort, that will take `O(n log n)`.

Comment: A set is not the correct data structure to use for this. Sets can't contain duplicate elements. If `user1` and `user2` are tied with the same score, only one of them will appear in the set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator, or let you class implement the comparable interface.
Take a look at: [Java : Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108604/java-comparable-vs-comparator)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Highscore> 
{
   public int compare(HighScore h1, HighScore h2) {
      return h1.getScore().compareTo(h2.getScore());
   }
}
```